# htaccess hellhole of the universe

Tags: .htaccess

Welcome to my doom.

My problem so far is something of a mystery. 
Rules that are working perfectly on my website online, but not on my localhost. The rules are rather simple, but I can't find the trick to solve the bloody nightmare.

I have an url like this one http://frostpath.lx/access/articles
It's a Virtual Host on WAMP localhost with this conf.

```
<VirtualHost frostpath.lx>
  ServerName frostpath.lx
  ServerAlias frostpath.lx
  DocumentRoot "E:/Projects/frostpath"
  <Directory "E:/Projects/frostpath/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

So far so good that seems to work, the site is on and running, css load, scripts, everything's so good. mod_rewrite is on, I checked and rechecked with different scripts found online.

But the beast ain't satified. .htaccess (I think the problems comes from there but who knows - I might have been focusing on the wrong thing for hours)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(access)$ access.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(access)\/([^\.]+)$ access.php?$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(access)\/([^\.]+)\/([^\.]+)$ access.php?$2&start=$3 [NC,L]
```

Basically,

http://frostpath.lx/access/articles this is only redirecting to access.php and doesn't show the articles.

http://frostpath.lx/access?articles this one works perfectly.

But I don't want a "?" I want a "/". Abide by the rules .htaccess!

I tried stuffs but no luck so far

```
/access.php?$2
/access?$2
/?access.php&$2
```

And everything above with and without slashes. Honestly I ask here because I'm running out of ideas.

Also, rules are working on my index.php but not on access.php which is another controller. Mindblown.

So what the hell is wrong with my rules?

Help me please, despair is slowly hurting my keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^access$ access.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^access/([^.]+)/([^.]+)$ access.php?$1&start=$2 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^access/([^.]+)$ access.php?$1 [NC,L]
```

With article rule before.

Or change your 2nd rule:

```
RewriteRule ^access/([^./]+)$ access.php?$1 [NC,L]
```

Because for now it also applies to the 3rd case, as / is included in the first group